# OWIN simple login not signing in

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, owin

I am attempting to use OWIN to login with a dead simple fixed authentication, but I can't seem to get it to work at all. I feel like I'm missing something very easy, but can't seem to figure it out. I don't need or care for anything except saving the email address of the person and have no desire for oauth, which is what most of the tutorials and samples seem to show. When I run the below code, I am never signed in and the Authentication claims are always empty when I look in the debugger.

My Razor web page:

```
@using System.Security.Claims;
@{

    Microsoft.Owin.IOwinContext ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
    var usr = Request["text1"];
    if (IsPost && usr == "valid@user.com")
    {
        ctx.Authentication.SignOut(Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        var claims = new List<Claim>();
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, usr));
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, var));
        var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        ctx.Authentication.SignIn(id);
        //FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("valid@user.com", false); // Also fails
    }
    var IP = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated.ToString();
    var text = "valid@user.com";

}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head><title></title></head>
    <body>
        <p>Are we Logged in? <strong>@IP</strong>.</p>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <p>
                <label for="text1">First Number:</label>
                <input type="text" name="text1" value="@text" />
            <p><input type="submit" value="Add" /></p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

with a startup class of

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(TypeScriptHTMLApp1.Startup1))]

namespace TypeScriptHTMLApp1
{
    public class Startup1
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType =DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie, 
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Why is it always returning false and how can I make it successfully login?

Comment: Are you running it locally?  Are you running it under SSL?  If you are not using SSL, have you set requireSsl="false" in your web.config (under system.identityModel.services - federationConfiguration - cookieHandler.  You should be seeing some cookies in the response after the SignIn method.  If you aren't, this is one possible reason.

Comment: Ah ha! That's it! I don't have SSL yet, and not requiring SSL fixed it. Mind making that an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running locally and not under SSL, make sure you instruct the cookie handler not to require SSL.  Otherwise it will never issue the cookie and it will seem like nothing is happening.  This had me stumped just last week.

```
   <system.identityModel.services>
      <federationConfiguration>
         <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" />
      </federationConfiguration>
   </system.identityModel.services>
```